# Thread safety when using coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines

I have been reading alot about Thread safety recently and I am wondering if I have done anything wrong in my code base. I need a peer review to help me identify if my code base is Thread safe or not.

When should I use the `synchronized block` to ensure Thread safety? In what circumstances do I have to use it? Will race condition affect my code below? Running the app works fine, however I would like to understand how Thread safety works in-depth

The `getNews` method is called in the `MainActivity`

```
`class NewsViewModel(var NewsRepositorys:NewsRepository) : ViewModel() 

{

var GeneralNews:MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val BusinessNews: MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val EntertainmentNews : MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val HealthNews : MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val ScienceNews: MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val SportsNews :  MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

val TechNews : MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> = MutableLiveData()

fun getNews(Country:String, Category:String, NewsList:MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?> ){

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ErrorGetNewsCall(Country, Category,NewsList )
    }

}


fun CallingNews(response: Response<NewsDataFromJson>): ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?> {

    when(response.code()){
        
        200 -> { val body = response.body()

        return ErrorHandling.Success(body)
            }
        400 -> {return ErrorHandling.Error("Bad Request")}
        401 -> {return ErrorHandling.Error("Your API key was missing from the request, or wasn't correct.")}
        429 -> {return ErrorHandling.Error("Too many requests")}
        else -> {return ErrorHandling.Error("Server error")}
    }
}

suspend fun ErrorGetNewsCall(country: String, Category: String, NewsList:MutableLiveData<ErrorHandling<NewsDataFromJson?>?>){
    try{
        val ApiResponse = NewsRepositorys.getNews(country,
            Category,

            "3af34c4172814610afe0a3e59dafafe4")

        NewsList.postValue(CallingNews(ApiResponse))

    }catch (Exceptions:Throwable){
        when(Exceptions){
            is IOException -> NewsList.postValue(ErrorHandling.Error("There is a network failure, please refresh the page!"))
            else -> NewsList.postValue(ErrorHandling.Error("Conversion Error"))
        }
    }

}
}`
```

My code works fine, I just need help reviewing it for Thread safety issues.

Comment: If you are looking for a code review, there's a separate site: codereview.stackexchange.com. If you have specific questions about how coroutines work, those can be asked here.